# how to persist the state of selected items in multichoic listview

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

can any one please tell me how to make the some items in multichoice list view get selected by default. I want some items to be selected by default when listview is fisttime diplayed.

Comment: You mean list-view with checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had same challenge and I used 2 dirty methods for quick fix

1. Keep the id of the list item selected in a global static variable or on SQLite
2. When relevant activity loaded check whether its null. if null do nothing else bold the text in the list

You can use these as last resort. Hope someone else will help you out with better answer.